# Cannot get Random Function to work properly in Discord.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, numbers, discord, discord.js

I am using the following code to create a random value and use that value to pick two different value from another two arrays...but it seems every time I run it, the result is always the same and not random. I am not sure what I am doing wrong. If anyone could help me that would be greatly appreciated!

```
    const Discord = require('discord.js');

const client = new Discord.Client();


const num = ['1','2','3','4'];
const numValue = randomImage(num);
const status = ['Dad','Mom','Son','Daughter'];
const statusValue = status[Number(numValue)-1];
const name = ['Bob','Linda','Jack','Jill'];
const nameValue = name[Number(numValue)-1];

    function randomImage(num) {
       return num[Math.floor(Math.random() * num.length)];
    }

client.on('message',(message=>{
  if(message.content === ">test"){
    message.channel.send(statusValue)
    message.channel.send(nameValue)
}

}))


client.login('Token')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because you aren't creating a new random number each message, when you load your code it generates it once,

```js
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const client = new Discord.Client();

const num = ['1','2','3','4'];
const status = ['Dad','Mom','Son','Daughter'];

function randomImage(num) {
   return num[Math.floor(Math.random() * num.length)];
}

client.on('message', message => {
  if(message.content === ">test"){
    const numValue = randomImage(num);
    const statusValue = status[Number(numValue)-1];
    const nameValue = name[Number(numValue)-1];
    
    message.channel.send(statusValue)
    message.channel.send(nameValue)
  }
});


client.login('Token')
```

Answer (score 1):

Well bescially you are calling the function `randomImage` one time and you need to call on each message. So just move the code inside the the message listner.

```js
client.on('message', (message => {
    if (message.content === ">test") {
        const numValue = randomImage(num); // <- randomimage is now called each time the users send message
        const statusValue = status[Number(numValue) - 1];
        const nameValue = name[Number(numValue) - 1];

        message.channel.send(statusValue)
        message.channel.send(nameValue)
    }
}))
```